# ASP.NET Credentials Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been working on an asp.net 4.0 website and seem to be having an issue with deleting from the database stored in the app_data folder.

I created a domain group in the actice directory and used the web.config file to restrict access to certain pages that allow modifcation of the database. Everything worked fine on my test machine and the production server, but the issue is that on the server, even though it recognizes the user when you access the page, when you try to delete an item it denies access and does not allow you to delete the item.

The users had read/write permissions to the folder, but it still denied access. I did some testing and allowed everyone read/write acces, and it allowed me to delete, but I don't like having that option set up.

Does anyone know what causes this issue and what the proper fix would be? I'm assuming I have to let the website know which user is running the application before it tries to delete so they can write to the database, but I thought it would do that automatically since I used Windows authentication.

If anyone has any information I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user account that is running the application pool for your website is the only user account that needs MODIFY permissions to that database file.

Comment: So even though I restrict access to specific domain users, they technically arn't the ones running the application? Does that mean I just have to give the folder MODIFY permissions on the server my application is running on?

Comment: That is correct: one specific user account (app pool user) is running your application. Your AD users are only accessing/using the application. Irrelevant to accessing your app_data folder, Windows authentication at IIS works in such a way that it solely considers physical file permissions while making decisions to authorize authenticated users, even though that logically shouldn't be necessary. If you want to be defining minimal permissions, then modify rule to just the db file; otherwise, it's fine to give modify permissions to the whole app_data folder.

Comment: Sounds good, so the users just access the site that the app pool is currently running, and the web.config file just checks if the person accessing it is the right user and denies access, so it doesn't matter who accesses the site if the app pool doesn't have the rights to write to the database. Thanks for the information. There is a lot of information out there and how to restrict access and set things up, but they never tell you the fine points of how the security systems work and the little things that need to be set up. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. There is also this special IUSR account, which represents ANONYMOUS user, but that's necessary on the whole website folder only when anonymous authentication is enabled. However, in your case, since you're using win-auth, anon-auth should be disabled.